# How to access "Applications" menu in Ubuntu Unity Desktop 

Tags: unity, appmenu

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 with the new Unity Desktop.  I understand that I can access the classic "Applications" menu by switching to Gnome.  However, I was wondering if it's possible to access the menu thru the Unity Desktop.  If not, then what is the best way to access the installed programs?

Comment: If @Tachyons's answer has solved your problem, then you might want to accept it.

Comment: thanks this helped me! used to old debian interface. You should accept answer OP and wish people would up vote question too and not only answer!

Answer (score 22):

Yes, if you need a classic menu in Unity you can use "classic menu indicator applet", press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal.

When it opens run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

To run the classicmenu immediately hit the <kbd>super</kbd> key, type `classic` then click the classicmenu icon. A new icon will appear in the top right hand corner near the clock.

[image]

Else you can open application via the Unity dash

[image]

**Links**

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/46811/39372
2. [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: You can right click on the ubuntu button on 12.04 to go right to "applications", not sure if this was in 11.10 though.

Comment: The “application menu” in the Unity dash does not show exactly the same applications. Actually, look at the screenshots above and count the entries in the Grapics category.

Comment: No, above screenshots are taken from diffrent computers

Comment: @Tachyons : Can I move this indicator from right to left side on top bar?

Comment: @Pandya No ,indicators can not be moved , left part is reserved for global menu