# Is it possible to get the menuing system in (top of screen) 10.04 back after upgrading?

Tags: desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access “Applications” menu in Ubuntu Unity Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122437/how-to-access-applications-menu-in-ubuntu-unity-desktop)

I was changing machines and decided to upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10.  The desktop changed significantly and I don't like the sliding panel on the left side of the screen and would prefer the menu on the top line of the screen from 10.04 (where the Admin, System, etc. utilities could be found).  Is there a way to get this menu back or is it lost forever?

I'm an intermediate Unix user and any help/insight is appreciated.

Comment: I thought the same when I first saw it, and so did many others, but in fact, if you stick with it for just a short period, you won't want to go back to the old desktop. It has many devilishly clever features that you will discover gradually, but will make usage easier for you. Grasp the idea and you won't look back.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`

Comment: @ Sun Dial: I would agree with you in 12.04, however he has the previious one, without the Dash etc

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go back to gnome classic, install the gnome-panel package, log out, and select gnome-classic in the lightdm session drop down. See [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed/) for more details.

You may also like [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/).  It is the default desktop for Linux Mint. There is a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable) for Ubuntu that has packages for 12.04. It has the look and feel of Classic Gnome, but with some nice new features like searchable menus.

I agree with Sun Dial, though, Unity is really nice once you get used to it. Once you catch the vision you won't look back.