# Categorized menus as it was pre-11.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access “Applications” menu in Ubuntu Unity Desktop (Ubuntu 11.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122437/how-to-access-applications-menu-in-ubuntu-unity-desktop-ubuntu-11-10)

How can I have menus as it was before unity?

[image]

Probably not on the desktop as was before but can I have those menus under *dash*? a *lense* maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available and can be installed with the command

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

remember to choose your desktop environment at the login prompt.

Comment: which desktop environment?

Comment: It's named "Gnome classic"

Comment: Then unity launcher would be gone. isn't it?

Comment: nope, you can choose, it's still there, you just have 1 more desktop to choose from.

Comment: what I meant you can use unity launcher and panel at the same time

Comment: No, you can't have unity and gnome-panel at the same time...

Comment: of course, it's another desktop environment, you have to choose.

Comment: @user827992 you should read the last line of the question

Answer (score 0):

<del>The feature not available with unity launcher.</del>

**Update: You can have this feature almost same with unity desktop but not exact. It will look like below**

[image: appmenu]

To do so: run following commands,

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

Alternatives:

1. Install [cairo-dock](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cairo-dock) [image: Install cairo-dock] and use it. Optionally hide the unity launcher.

   [image: cairodock]
2. Install [gnome-shell](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-shell) [image: Install gnome-shell] and choose gnome classic at login screen. **But you will loose unity**

   [image]

Comment: `gnome-shell` is the most popular interface for Gnome 3, `cairo-dock` is just a dock, this has nothing to do with this topic.

Comment: is it so? you should look once more in the screen shot. using `cairo-dock` you got the grouping and the unity too.(The most relevant solution as per topic ) `gnome-shell` also include gnome2 classic.

Comment: yes, but not "as it was pre-11.04"

Comment: I said alternative/ most relevant not exact :)