# Where is the Applications menu

Tags: appmenu

At [How do I get rid of the keyring-password-prompt](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-keyring-password-prompt/) on one.ubuntu.com I got to read:

> Open Applications->Accessories->Passwords And Encryption Keys
>   or on Ubuntu 11.04 press the "super key" (Windows key on most keyboards) and type "Passwords"
>   then click on "Passwords and Encryption Keys

I don't see any Applications menu.

Comment: yes press the "super key" (Windows key on most keyboards) and type "Passwords" then click on "Passwords and Encryption Keys"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access "Applications" menu in Ubuntu Unity Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122437/how-to-access-applications-menu-in-ubuntu-unity-desktop)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The suggested dupe explains how to install such Applications menu to use alongside Unity Dash. However, in this case the OP fails to access an application, does he really need to install the menu to find it?...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application menu was/is a menu for gnome-fallback/gnome-classic interface. It is not available with unity. To access applications in unity, there is a simpler way; Just press `Super key` and type the name of what application you want.

Answer (score 0):

... or use `Synapse`, which (won't give you a list, but) performs like a magic wand, waiting to be swished !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ctrl + F` right from home screen to search for it.